# How to store all global data of running process in visual studio

Tags: visual-c++, global, symbols, dump

I would like to store all global symbols of a process running  on visual studio in run time and I will be using this information later....Is there a way to do this ??

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but see if this helps: [Crash Dump Analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416349.aspx), [Minidump Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680369.aspx)

Comment: That's usually done with a database.